# Summernote - Insert Text and keep formatting style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, summernote

I am currently trying to insert a string of text from a dropdown list into the Summernote text editor.  However, upon insertion, the string closes any formatting tags, such as <'strong'>, <'p'>, and more.

Here is an example of the HTML after I have inserted the string "AND"

**Bob** AND **I** **Loves Ice Cream and Cake.  How about You?**

```
<p><span style="font-size: 12px;"><b>Bob </b></span>AND <span style="font-size: 12px;">
<b>I&nbsp;</b></span><span style="font-size: 12px;">
<b>Loves Ice Cream and Cake. &nbsp;How about You?</b></span>
```

I need to be able to prevent the auto-closing and auto-opening of tags to the right and to the left of where the cursor was.  I was looking into using the insertNode() and insertText() functions, but both of these end up doing the same thing.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a sample of the code that inserts at the cursor.  I am currently extending Summernote's button with the UppercaseButton.

```
 var UppercaseButton = function (context) {
    var ui = $.summernote.ui;

    // create button
    var button = ui.button({
        contents: '<i class="fa fa-child"/> Uppercase',
        tooltip: 'Highlight a data attribute that you would like to make uppercase',
        click: function () {

            var range = $('#taBody').summernote('createRange');
            var newText = range.toString();
            console.log("newText: " + newText);
            console.log(range);
            context.invoke("editor.insertText", newText.toUpperCase());
        }
    });

    return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to modify the html please?

Comment: Yup, I went ahead and added a snippet!

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? I'm passing for the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach. This should grab the current node context the cursor is in and then append the desired text into that node

```js
function insertAtCaret(text) {
        // deleteContents() will replace any text that is currently highlighted, if any
        let newRange = $("#taBody").summernote("getLastRange").deleteContents();

        // Insert the desired text inside the formatted tag of the first part of the highlighted text. That way the formatting applies to the inserted text
        newRange.sc.textContent = newRange.sc.textContent.substring(0, newRange.so) + text + newRange.sc.textContent.substring(newRange.so, newRange.sc.textContent.length);

        // Update the cursor position to just after the inserted text
        $("#taBody").summernote('setLastRange', $.summernote.range.create(/* start container */newRange.sc, /* start offset */ newRange.so + text.length).select());
    }

var UppercaseButton = function (context) {
    var ui = $.summernote.ui;

    // create button
    var button = ui.button({
        contents: '<i class="fa fa-child"/> Uppercase',
        tooltip: 'Highlight a data attribute that you would like to make uppercase',
        click: function () {
            insertAtCaret(newText.toUpperCase())
        }
    });

    return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
}
```